# Create github pages on github, but local is up to date?

Tags: git, github-pages, readme

I am quite new to git, but I have my git hub page here for playing around with Santanders Product Recommendation data set from Kaggle.  I have been updating and pushing my commits to git over the last week.  No problem.

I now want to add a gitpage to summarise the problem so that people don't have to go through my code.

I tried to set this up in /docs, but it wouldn't work.  It only worked when I used the master branch, and only when I used readme.md which I would have guessed is bad practise.... This would be a nice to have if possible.  If not, I will create another documentation file in the docs file.

What I do not understand, is that when I created the page, it adjusted the readme.md on github.  A config file has also been added.
When I then run git status in bash to then update my local files, it tells me that the "Branch is up to date with origin/master"

I tested if I add another doc on local and go through the steps to push it up (status/ add . /commit/push origin master), and it told me there were differences.

I tried git pull, and it told me there was a merge.mng file that was duplicated.  I deleted one.  In bash, it now wants me to write a message about why the merge is necessary... which in theory is fine but I don't seem to be able to enter/submit that message.

So I have now got myself into a position where I can no longer update my git...

Below is the current message I get from git bash, which I cannot move on from.

```
Merge branch 'master' of 
https://github.com/jamesoliver1981/Kaggle_Santander_ProdRec
"merge to source gh pages file"
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
~
~
...
~
<it/Kaggle_Santander_ProdRec/.git/MERGE_MSG[+] [unix] (07:58 
07/02/2019)1,32 All
-- INSERT --
```

***EDIT
I haven't set an upstream because this is the same repo - I am the only contributor.  Do I need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I want to make sure you're using the basic workflow for git:

```
git add [file]

git commit -m "This is my message for the commit"

git push
```

This workflow makes your commits have messages and works for me 99% of the time. You might just be trying to do things way more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Yep, I am using that.  I have been doing add . rather than add [file] but would that make a difference?  I think the issue comes from doing something on the repo rather than locally

Comment: Could be. Very hard for me to think of what possibly went wrong there, since I don't really know what you've done. If you haven't done too much locally, you can always delete your local copy and clone the project again from GitHub.

Comment: What's odd is that, I crashed out of the merge (closed bash). I log back in and then it tells me my local machine is 3 steps ahead of branch. This isn't true, as the changes on the report haven't been pulled to my local machine. How should I update my local machine. Is it not just git fetch, git merge? Do I need more? Like setting up the upstream

Comment: I don't know what I did but I took your suggestion of cloning the repo.  I have now checked that this works and I am able to make updates both ways.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For others, also check the dates of your posts. I just had this problem. I'm at UTC+11 and I'm pretty sure the server is at UTC. Thus if I date my posts with my local time, the server thinks they are in the future and won't build them. Using UTC avoided this for me.

As mentioned by joao cenoura in the comments below:

*you can tell jekyll to show "future" posts by adding future: true to your _config.yml

*and/or add timezone: TIMEZONE to specify your timezone.

Comment: Thank you for this.  How can I see what my timezones are to see tat I have a difference?  Also I cannot see the comment you mention.  You think that if I align my timezones then it won't see any issues?  How do I get out of the merge page in git bash? Or should I just close it and no changes will be made?

Comment: Also given I have updated the repo and I want to get the same information on my local machine, is git pull and then git merge the correct steps?